# How do I turn off the gcc preprocessor on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have googled "turning off the gcc preprocessor on Linux" for a good while now (using that exact phrase) and everything has been irrelevant. For example I want to turn off everything **except** the preprocessor (the opposite of what I want) or pressurising warnings. Does anyone know of a way to disable the preprocessor? I found one that Facebook developed and claimed is faster, and I would like to test it out.

Comment: I believe the preprocessor will become a no-op if the sources were already preprocessed, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Name your newer/other preprocessor `cpp` and put it earlier in your path?  or rename original `cpp` to `cpp-other`, then name yours `cpp` also.  Basically just replace it in the normal tool-chain.  That's your ultimate goal, isn't it?  To replace cpp with another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested what lornix said in a comment, and it works:

Name the other/newer preprocessor "cpp" and put it in your path, and rename the original cpp to cpp-other or cpp-orig. It'll work great considering you are attempting to replace cpp anyways.

Comment: So, did whoever decided to downvote my answer two years (on the dot) later have some sort of feedback?

Answer (score 8):

Name your file `program.i` instead of `program.c` and it will be treated as already pre-processed by GCC/Clang and sent directly to the compiler.

Example:

```
$ cat t.i
int printf(const char *f, ...);

int main(){
  printf("hello world\n");
}
$ gcc t.i && ./a.out 
hello world
```

Comment: Solid. I was trying to explain a similar thing in my answer, but this version is better.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently found a solution to the problem stated in the title (regardless of what the ultimate goal was) which seems cleaner than changing the extension of the source file, so I record it in hope that someone will find it useful: tell GCC that the source file has already been preprocessed,

```
gcc -x cpp-output -o hello hello.c
```